# Way of binding scss files in angular project

Tags: angular, sass

I'm struggling to use sass in fresh angular project. I created project with `--style=scss` flag from CLI and then updated `.angular-cli.json` file content with `"styleExt": "scss"` and `"styles": ["styles.scss"]`. Project building was successfull but styles from files like `xyz.component.scss` were not compiled and thus not included in styles bundle.

I managed to add components style files to `.angular-cli.json` file `"styles": ["styles.scss", "./path/to/file/xyz.component.scss"]` but this resulted in runtime error: `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings`.

To avoid this error I deleted `styleUrls: ['./xyz.component.scss']` from `@Component` annotations in `xyz.component.ts` files.

Now everything works good but I don't understand whats going on with those scss files. Why I must delete reference to them from `@Component`? (they are referenced automaticly when using `ng g component` cli command). Are there any other options to make it work without referencing `.scss` files in `.angular-cli.json` and use `@Component` reference instead?

My version setup:

```
@angular/cli: 1.2.7
node: 6.10.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.3.3
@angular/common: 4.3.3
@angular/compiler: 4.3.3
@angular/core: 4.3.3
@angular/forms: 4.3.3
@angular/http: 4.3.3
@angular/platform-browser: 4.3.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.3.3
@angular/router: 4.3.3
@angular/cli: 1.2.7
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.3.3
@angular/language-service: 4.3.3
```

Comment: What if you open a new project from scratch? `ng new my-proj --style=scss`? Does that work for you?

Comment: @GioraGuttsait I also tried to create new project with that command but result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved component styles problem by uninstalling `angular-cli` and reinstalling it in `1.4.7` version. Then generating new project with `--style=scss`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your telling NG CLI that you want to use SASS, but then your trying to feed it scss files.

If you want to write SCSS then change your flag to SCSS.

```
ng new My_New_Project --style=scss
```

vs

```
ng new My_New_Project --style=sass
```

Also, you just need to run the command you should not have to change any other config or delete anything especially if your generating components.

```
ng generate component [name]
```

**NG CLI Update**

Global

`npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

Local

`rm -rf node_modules dist # use rmdir /S/Q node_modules dist in Windows Command Prompt; use rm -r -fo node_modules,dist in Windows PowerShell
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install`

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli

Comment: Oh my bad, it was a typo in my question info. I created project with `ng new test --style=scss` and with `ng new test` and then used `ng set defaults.styleExt scss`. In both cases results were the same (like described in question).

Comment: Interesting, You should still not have to `ng set defaults.styleExt scss` or anything unless you are converting from an existing project. What version of ng cli are you using? `ng --version`

Comment: I know that there are two methods of working with scss in angular project. Thats why I tried working from scratch using scss (`ng new test --style=scss`) and created new project via `ng new test` and then converted it into scss (`ng set defaults.styleExt scss`). In both projects results were the same as in question description. My cli version is included in question description as well as other component versions (`@angular/cli: 1.2.7`) .

Comment: Right sorry about that got caught up in the chase.

Not that I think this is your issue but it might be worth updating to the latest version of CLI currently 1.3. They have a ton of bug fixes. Added update info to answer

Comment: Still nothing. I updated cli to latest version `1.4.7` and .scss files are still omitted.